# What sorting algorithm delivers one page of results the fastest?  (partial result set)

Tags: .net, sorting, quicksort, heapsort

I have a "large" dataset where I need to display the first or last 10 rows of data and allow the sort operation to operate in the background as the user views the first page of results.

> **Edit**: Details on what "large" means
>
> I am collecting Syslog and EventLog data for several hosts into a searchable repository.  Since I will be looking at N computers that burst/spam event log data in varying intervals the item that I search upon can grow quickly if it's not in the default order of `Machine\Log\Event DateTime`
>
> Based on the answer I receive I may populate a secondary index upon inserting the data so that the initial view is very efficient.

I think it would be inefficient to sort all the data first, and then deliver the entire result set when 80% of the time the user only cares about the first or last 10 entries.

What is the best algorithm to deliver a partial result set, and continue processing in the background?

[Based on this sample](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com), the heap, quick sort, and shell seem to offer the best performance and might offer one page of results out of the box.

How would I tell when any of those algorithms are ready to serve the first page?  What threshold would I watch?

Comment: What is the source of what you want to sort?  XML file, Database, File Directory?

Comment: My guess is that your result set it too small to show a discernible difference to actually tell that it will be faster to sort the first 10 rows vs the entire result set. That being said, what is your definition of large?  That will give us a better understanding the problem and how to help.

Comment: @Erik Phillips I think I just need an abstract sorting class; I'm not sure where the data will be: a CSV feed, a list of Azure Blobs, or Azure table.  I'd be curious about your train of thought

Comment: If you have 100 records in sql, telling sql to sort them each time is fine.  If you have 1 billion XElements in a file, probably would be best to sort it once and either cache it in memory or (re)save it in a sorted fashion.  Where your records come from and how many have a huge impact on this type of decision.  Additionally most sort algorithms I am aware of only work if you sort ALL the data to get the first/last set of data, otherwise you can't guarantee they are the first/last set.

Comment: @Kevin updated per your request

Answer (score 1):

You can select the top K items in `O(n)` time. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Selecting_k_smallest_or_largest_elements. You could use a Quickselect algorithm to select the top 10 (which would put them at the front of the array), do it again for the bottom 10 (put at the end of the array), and then have the sort run in the background, sorting items 10 through n-10.

In practice, Heapselect is faster than Quickselect when the number of items you want to select is less than 1% of the total number of items. That is to select `k` items from a list of `n`, you should use Heapselect if `k < n/100`. If `k` is 10 and `n` is a million, Heapselect is going to be hugely faster than Quickselect.

The disadvantage of Heapselect is that it requires O(k) extra space. But when `k == 10`, that's not a big deal.

It depends on the nature of your data. If the total number of rows to be displayed is usually more than 1,000, then you should use Heapselect. Otherwise, use Quickselect. They're both easy to implement.

See [When Theory Meets Practice](http://blog.mischel.com/2011/10/25/when-theory-meets-practice/) for more information on the difference between the two selection algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

> Based on this sample, the heap, quick sort, and shell seem to offer
>   the best performance and might offer one page of results out of the
>   box.

To do this you are going to need an algorithm that sorts the list in order.  Each iteration of of the list places the next largest (or smallest) element in the list it's proper place. So, after the first pass, the smallest element is in position 1, and after the second pass the second smallest is in position 2.  To do this you are going to need something like a Selection Sort][2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort).

Here's the problem compared to other algorithms in and data order, these can be vastly outperformed.  So even though you are "quickly" grabbing the first 10 records after they are sorted, another algorithm might have sorted the entire list in the same amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the top K items can be done in O(nlogk) time, which is much, much faster than O(nlogn), using a heap Or eventually a priority queue.
The strategy is to go through the list once, and as you go, keep a list of the top k elements that you found so far. To do this efficiently, you have to always know the smallest element in this top-k, so you can possibly replace it with one that is larger. The heap structure makes it easy to maintain this list without wasting any effort.

You can also use selection algorithm mentioned at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm for finding the first k smallest or largest entries in your list. which is faster that sorting the entire list.

I would suggest that you sort k entries first and display the result and in back ground sort the remaining entries using merge, heap or quick sort.